# Apache Alias / VirtualHost run as different user

Tags: php, apache-2.2, alias, httpd

I tried to create an alias or virtual host to run as different user.
Well below is part of apache `httpd.conf` that doesn't work.
Or, is it even possible?

```
<VirtualHost blah:80>

    user DifferentUser
    group DifferentGroup

    ServerAdmin blah
    DocumentRoot blah
    ServerName blah
    ServerAlias blah
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ blah
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm default.htm index.shtml index.php
    ErrorLog logs/blah-error_log
    CustomLog logs/blah-access_log common
    <Directory "/blah/">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
      AllowOverride all
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from none
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 5):

You may be able to utilise the [mpm-itk](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/) module which is available for some Linux distros. Failing that you can usee other technologies for privilege separation e.g. [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html) or some other things [here](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PrivilegeSeparation).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. User and group directives can be set only in server context.